# If $G$ has inverse of all elements, then $G$ is a group. $($ true / false$) ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ has inverse of all elements, then $G$ is a group. $($ true / false$) ?$

I know a group satisfies closure property, associativity. It has a unique identity element and inverses for all elements.

I can't find any counter example to prove the statement false. If the statement is true, then how existence of inverses of all elements imply that $G$ is a group?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to define $G$. Is $G$ a set equipped with a binary operation? Is $G$ closed under the binary operation? Anything else?

Comment: The unit sphere in $\mathbb R^8$ has a product operation with inverses that is not associative.

Comment: @MattSamuel Is there a (smallish) finite substructure of $\mathbb{R}^8$ that also serves as a counterexample?

Comment: @Mike Probably. Rather than trying to find that though it would probably be easier to directly construct a finite example.

Comment: The question is a bit vague in terms of restriction on set $G$.  For example, we can have a trivial example as $G=\Bbb{Z}-\{0\}$, then we can say $G$ has additive inverses but is not closed, hence not a group.

Comment: @Mike For example, let $G=\{e, a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}\}$. $e$ is the identity. Besides the inverse pairs implied by the notation, you can define products arbitrarily. Should be easy to make it nonassociative.

Answer (score 0):

No, groupoids (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid?wprov=sfla1) are a counterexample.